# How to convert .po to .mo files on mac?

Tags: internationalization, translation, gettext, po, mo

I have tried using poedit 1.4.6>save as, but .mo is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, simple yet unclear, Whenever you save a file as .po using poedit, it automatically saves a .mo file aswell. (.mo being the compiled version of the languagefile)

Answer (score 5):

Install gettext, then run the msgfmt command on the files.

```
> brew install gettext
> msgfmt inputfile.po -o outputfile.mo
```