# How to open a MO gnu gettext file?

Tags: r, documentation, multilingual, po, mo

I am reviewing how to address multi-language support for documentation and messaging with a library.  I found that the `MASS` package uses such support, and I wanted to review the how and why.  For example, the ITALIAN pot/po file is compressed or binarized into MO form:

```
MASS_7.3-58.1\MASS\inst\po\it\LC_MESSAGES\R-MASS.mo
```

The question is:  how do I open the `R-MASS.mo` file to see its ITALIAN contents or convert to a non-binary PO form?

I have installed `gnu gettext` on both WINDOZE and a DEBIAN Oracle VirtualBox.  I have read the MAN page, and don't see how to extract MO files.  Maybe there is an R Script that reads the binary to perform the necessary conversion?  [ Similar to readRDB for .rdx/.rdb files, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62394942/184614 ]

Comment: When you installed `gettext`, did it also install `msgfmt`? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62283548/2372064

Answer (score 0):

Use gettext's `msgunfmt` utility to extract all strings from a MO file:

```
msgunfmt MASS_7.3-58.1\MASS\inst\po\it\LC_MESSAGES\R-MASS.mo
```